# Normalize gray image and save as RGB

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a Xray image that is a gray image. It contains some brightness region. I want to normalize the image and save it as RGB (.png). This is my code

```
img = cv2.imread('input.jpg', 0)
img=(img-img.mean())/ img.std()
img = img[:, :, None]
rgb=np.concatenate((img, img,img), axis=2)
cv2.imwrite('normalize.png', rgb)
```

The code can run without error. However, the output is an integer range (likes binary image). What should I change? Thanks

Update: This is example image that ranges in [0-255]. I want to normalize it to the range [0-1] and save it to .png image.

[image]

Comment: Inspect the data type and range of values in `img` after you've performed the transformation on the second line. Note: A floating point image should have values in the range `[0.0-1.0]`.

Comment: I am not aware of OpenCv supporting PNGs with floating point values.

Comment: So, do we have another option?

Comment: @Piglet It seems to just convert the float array to `uint8` without applying any scaling or saturation.

Comment: @user8264 Question is, what you're actually trying to achieve. Can you show a sample input image, and either describe or show the desired result?

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question. I want to normalize the intensity range and save it to png image

Comment: yes it will just  cut off the decimal places. so 0.12 becomes 0, 3.123 becomes 3 and so on. why should it scale anything? you never told the software to do that.  if you want to normalize something to [0-1] you cannot just subtract the mean. it will cause negative values. and standard formats like PNG are for displayable image data. it wouldn't make sense to store values in your desired range as they would appear black. you'll most likely have to use some special file format as this is a special application

Comment: as @DanMašek already asked you, what is the purpose of this and why do you need png?

Comment: I see. So can we save another type that can store float number. Is it bmp type?

Comment: No, bmp won't do it. Most image formats are integer only. I think maybe TIFF could handle it but I've never tried it.

Comment: P.S. Saving floating point pixel values is very wasteful for a natural image, it's more typical to leave it as integer values in the file and do any necessary conversions as part of the image processing pipeline.